# PASSAR FÓRMULA SQL EM ACCESS (TEXT MINING)

Tags: sql, oracle, microsoft-access

Boa tarde!
Estou passando uma fórmula em sql para o access

```
WHEN ((SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%VISITAD%')
                                         OR  (SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%FACHAD%')
                                         OR  (SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%INSTALA%')
                                         OR  (SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%ESTOQUE%')
THEN 1 ELSE 0
                                  END IN_TXT_MING_VISIT
```

Nesse caso, estou procurando essas palavas no campo SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA e retorna 1 se achar o resultado e 0 se não achar.. isso no oracle.
Porém quero fazer o mesmo no ACCESS, porém não estou conseguindo, alguém pode me dar um help?

Comment: Neste trecho que você postou  falta um `)`. Tente `IIF((SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%VISITAD%') OR  (SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%FACHAD%') OR  (SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%INSTALA%') OR (SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA LIKE '%ESTOQUE%'), 1, 0)`.

Comment: Quando utilizo essa fórmula me retorna 0 mesmo encontrando a palavra, o mais perto que cheguei foi usando IIF(INSTR(SA_P1_RESULT_VISITA,"VISITAD")>0,1,0), mas está me retornando -1 e eu tenho que ficar utilizando essa formula inteira para todas palavras ;\

Comment: Cara, consegui agora, descobri que no access se utiliza "*" e não "%" kkkkkk